# Type 'UIView' has no member 'layoutFittingCompressedSize

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods

After updating the Xcode to latest version one of the pod file code is getting error. Tried to fix, but could not find the solution . The pod file I used was "MMTextureChat" and in that dropdown.swift is showing the error.
The code which I got error was

```
        let width = templateCell.systemLayoutSizeFitting(UILayoutFittingCompressedSize).width
```

And the error was "Type 'UIView' has no member 'layoutFittingCompressedSize'"

So what is the solution

Comment: What are the Xcode, swift and iOS versions that you are using?

Comment: The Xcode version is 9.4.1, swift version is 4.1 and minimum deployment target version is 10.0

Answer (score 4):

Has been renamed to `UILayoutFittingCompressedSize`

```
let meBetterSize = myView.systemLayoutSizeFitting(UIView.layoutFittingCompressedSize)
```

Comment: .width is to be removed

Answer (score 4):

Swift4: `myView.systemLayoutSizeFitting(UIView.layoutFittingCompressedSize)`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a Swift 4.2 answer

systemLayoutSizeFitting(UILayoutFittingCompressedSize).height